# Current Bitcoin symbol: Who designed it, when and why?

Tags: history, bitcoin-symbol

I am looking for informations about the authors of the current symbol used for Bitcoin. I am also interested about any brand design explainations such as graphic guidelines, and the way this symbol was adopted (contest, vote, imposition…). As a supporter of the symbol [Ƀ](http://www.ecogex.com/bitcoin/), I am not sure this choice was right.

Answer (score 6):

The very first icon (created by Satoshi) is visible here:
https://bitcointalk.org/oldSiteFiles/images/screen3.png

Satoshi later updated this using the B with two vertical strokes
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=64.0
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVz22.png

He never posted much about *why* he chose this symbol. It was not in use before Satoshi put it in the logo.

The current Bitcoin-Qt logo was created by bitboy:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1631.0

This logo replaced Satoshi's old one when the bitcoin.org GUI was rewritten from wxwidgets to Qt by Wladimir van der Laan. I don't think there was much discussion about it.

Comment: The links are broken.